# Rider cannot detect .NET core installation on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, rider

As instructed by the Rider IDE, I installed the .NET Core framework from Microsoft. I know that the installation was successful since I am able to run the `dotnet` command from my terminal. However, after restarting Rider, I still get the following message:

> Cannot detect .NET Core. Please install .NET Core and restart Rider.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue setting

```
/opt/dotnet/dotnet
```

in

```
Settings | Build,Execution,Deployment |
  Toolset and Build | .NET Core CLI executable path
```

[image]

Previously, I was using `/usr/bin/dotnet`, but it doesn't work anymore. Also, auto detect seems to be broken.

Actually, `/usr/bin/dotnet`, the path returned by `which dotnet`, is just a shell file defering to `/opt/dotnet/dotnet`, as its content is:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet
exec /opt/dotnet/dotnet $@

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

Comment: I installed SDK and runtime and it was showing that it was installed but in Rider it wasn't working I did as you changed the path in the build settings I essentially copied the directory from /usr/share/dotnet to /opt/dotnet and now it works. I was on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 8):

I was just experiencing this issue due to a botched install of [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) Android on Arch Linux and was able to resolve it by doing the following:

First execute `dotnet --info` to get the path of ***.NET Core SDKs installed***:

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   2.1.500 
> Commit:    b68b931422 
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     arch  OS Version:    OS Platform: 
> Linux  RID:         arch-x64  Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/ 
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 2.1.6   Commit:  3f4f8eebd8 
>
> ***.NET Core SDKs installed: 
>
> 2.1.500 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]***
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 
> [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App] 
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs: 
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Up one directory at ***/opt/dotnet/*** there should be an executable named "dotnet." The absolute path to this file (***/opt/dotnet/dotnet***) should be set as the ***.NET Core CLI executable path*** value under *File* → *Settings* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Toolset and Build* settings in Rider.

Just in case, here are my other toolset configuration settings:

***Mono executable path:*** /usr/bin/mono

***Use MSBuild version:*** Auto detected (15,0), /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/bin/MSBuild.dll

I also have the following values added to my PATH in *.bashrc* due to an error I received regarding [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) not being found:

> export MSBuildSDKsPath=/opt/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Sdks
>
> export PATH=${PATH}:${MSBuildSDKsPath}

Answer (score 3):

Solution adapted from [this answer on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-82361/Rider-cannot-run-apps-and-unable-to-detect-.Net-Core-but-dotnet-command-shows-correct-info#focus=Comments-27-7276512.0-0).

Add the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable in the file `launchsettings.json`. In my case, it was:
`"DOTNET_ROOT": "/usr/share/dotnet"`

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks! (Rider on Ubuntu with .NET 8.0.1 from Microsoft package repositories)

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me. I am on PopOS and found a solution [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005821160-Cannot-detect-NET-Core-Please-install-NET-Core-SDK-and-restart-Rider-) shown in the below screenshot. I think in general it is still a bad idea to install anything from Jetbrains through the Snap store. I've had issues with Intellij and Pycharm as well dating back to ~2014 that were immediately resolved by not using the Snap store.

[image]

Comment: Installed using flatpak. Similar issue. Then used the JetBrains Toolbox and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the path to .NET CLI in Rider settings: menu File* → *Settings* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Toolset and Build*. But usually Rider should auto detect it.

Please check what you have `dotnet` in your PATH. Pay attention; you should restart Rider after installing the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: @Philippe I'm running into this same problem on Arch after trying to get Xamarin.Android working. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Also on Arch. I downgraded to the previous version of dotnet (2.1.5). They show up now

Comment: @masterwok on Arch, with DotNet (2.1.500) and Rider (2018.2.3) I managed to fix the issue specifying `/opt/dotnet/dotnet` in `Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Toolset and Build/.NET Core CLI executable path`

Answer (score 1):

My solution was run command `dotnet new console` on root of project. Then, the templates are showed.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case despite installing `dotnet-sdk-7.0` and `dotnet --version` command returning correct version, I've been seeing no SDK in `dotnet --info`.**

The problem was that I had dotnet packages installed from different sources. There are a few sources you can download dotnet package: official Ubuntu feed and Microsoft feed. **I wanted to use Microsoft feed, as it provided newer versions of dotnet for my distro version, but actually used both.**

Here is how you can list all your dotnet packages:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep dotnet
```

Here is how you can check source of your packages:

```
sudo apt policy dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

### How to fix it

You just need to follow [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu#i-need-a-version-of-net-that-isnt-provided-by-my-linux-distribution). You need to get rid of official Ubuntu packages and install all of them from one source.

So:
Remove all dotnet packages:

```
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
```

Create files for apt preferences:

```
touch /etc/apt/preferences
```

Inside this file, paste this text. It will configure APT to ignore packages with those names in specific package source:

```
Package: dotnet* aspnet* netstandard*
Pin: origin "<your-package-source>"
Pin-Priority: -10
```

So if you configure it like this:

```
Package: dotnet* aspnet* netstandard*
Pin: origin "archive.ubuntu.com"
Pin-Priority: -10
```

It will ignore packages from `archive.ubuntu.com`. So when you install `dotnet-sdk-7.0` again, it will omit `archive.ubuntu.com` and install it from Microsoft source.

You may have different package sources, depending on distro, you can check it like this:

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the rather silly mistake of installing .NET Core **runtime** but forgetting about .NET Core **SDK** (so the `dotnet` tool still worked). Once I actually installed the SDK, Rider instantly detected it (.NET 3.1 and Rider 2019.3).

The suggestion to use `dotnet --info` [by masterwok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739309/rider-cannot-detect-net-core-installation-on-ubuntu/53437881#53437881) quickly highlights this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Neither reinstallation nor path `opt/lib64/dotnet` works for me.

I have to use the path `/var/run/host/usr/lib64/dotnet` for .NET cli executable path SDK instead.

Source: https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.Rider/issues/36#issuecomment-1154737584

Answer (score 0):

The root cause, in my case, was leftover configuration files from a previous installation of dotnet-sdk from the Ubuntu repositories. I had removed them and installed the packages from the Microsoft packages repository. But I had not *completely* removed them.

The cause was incorrect paths set in `/etc/dotnet/install_location` and `/etc/dotnet/install_location_x64`

The solution was to run `sudo apt-get purge dotnet-host-8.0`

I was put on track to this solution by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392932/1155779) answer from Amjad Abujamous. He was nice enough to include a link to his source, where I found an explanation of the root cause: [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-82361/Rider-cannot-run-apps-and-unable-to-detect-.Net-Core-but-dotnet-command-shows-correct-info#focus=Comments-27-8087170.0-0)